Android Chrome: Cannot Click Saved Password Button
Hope someone can help me with something that just recently started happening, and I have no idea why.
When I open a site in Android Chrome for which I have saved passwords, I am properly promoted to select the saved username from a pop-up dialog that asks "Use Saved Password?" With a button showing the username and obscured password to click beneath. Other times the button is located right above the keyboard.
In every instance in the past, clicking on the button inserts both the saved username and the password into the correct fields in order to log into the account. But now, for some reason, those buttons do not click at all. No matter what I do, no matter where or how hard I press, the button does not respond, it's as if the touch screen stopped working.
I have no idea why this happening and it's driving me absolutely crazy. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Moderator's note to the visitors: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. If you have the same problem, please don't post an answer. Instead, please "follow" the question so that you will be notified of any new answers (you have to have an account first). If you have a solution/workaround, then feel free to post an answer. Thanks.

There's a suggested edit to the question mentioning that "updating Google Play fixed this issue," in case anyone want to confirm and convert it to an answer here.

There's another question that also included the solution by "applying the Android system's security updates", in case anyone want to confirm and convert it to an answer here.

I found a solution, delete the latest update in Chrome.

I saw somewhere that changing your keyboard to Gboard would help, though it didn't work for me.

Issue has been fixed in a chrome update today April 24.
